# Convert big email attachments to www link

Tags: email, sendmail, postfix-mta

i'm running a mail server that serves mostly architects. the usage of those guys in email is mostly for sending files. today, our mail sending files is limited to about 20MB but the limit is because many webservers reject email that are bigger then 20MB.

what i would like to achieve is that when sending files that are larger then 20MB just to save the files aside and generate a link to download instead.

i would like to know:

1. are there any plugin to courier that do it?
2. what tools to i need to use to develop such a plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to make MTA replace large attachments with links to a centrally-stored copy [MIMEDefang Milter for sendmail/postfix/...]

You may consider using [MIMEDefang milter](http://www.mimedefang.org/) available under GPL license for sendmail and [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html).

### [MIMEDefang Description](http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/mimedefang)

---

**Mail Inspection and Modification**

MIMEDefang can inspect and modify e-mail messages as they pass through your mail relay. MIMEDefang is written in Perl, and its filter actions are expressed in Perl, so it's highly flexible. Here are some things that you can do very easily with MIMEDefang:

- Delete or alter attachments based on file name, contents, results of a virus scan, attachment size, etc.
- Replace large attachments with links to a centrally-stored copy to ease the burden on POP3 users with slow modem links.
  [...]

---